How to tell with git whether an original commit that was reversed is the same as the new recommit?
Commit history looks like this
1. aaa original code 
2. bbb the change 
3. ccc unrelated change 1 
4. ddd reversed bbb for some reason
5. eee unrelated change 2

Now code author wants to merge a PR with change fff in it. Author claims that this PR is just reversing ddd -- so it should exactly put back bbb.
How can PR reviewer verify that bbb and fff are identical commits (in other words, no further edits were made that need to be re-reviewed). What git command(s) can we use to test this claim?
I found this question Is there a way to check if two different git commits are equal in content? but those answers only work if the commits are in different branches or if you have extra non-git tools on the system. I need an answer that works on MS Windows without additional tools like diff, sed, awk, etc.

Probably the easiest thing is to rebase so that you have aaa-ccc'-eee'-bbb'-ddd'-fff' and verify that the tree underlying fff' is the same as the tree for bbb'

So to check whether fff's content could be the result of aaa and bbb and ccc and eee, produce that history and compare that content to fff's content. You already have the aaa bbb ccc history, you just want eee without ddd:
git checkout ccc
git cherry-pick eee
git rev-parse @^{tree} fff^{tree}    # or @: fff: for short

and if the two lines of rev-parse output the same id, the trees are identical.

@LeGEC ah. true. I first did it with git cherry-pick -n to avoid needless commits and took that out to simplify, I'll do another pass.

also: note that, if the hashes do not match, you can inspect the diff git diff @ fff to see what the differences are -- if they are trivial things like "git chose to insert a blank line between these two hunks" or if there are actual differences in the code.

You can compare "the diffs" rather than the content:
# the diff introduced by `bbb`:
git diff aaa bbb > /tmp/patch.bbb.txt

# the diff introduced by the merge request:
git diff eee...that/branch > /tmp/patch.mr.txt

# compare the 2, using any tool:
diff /tmp/patch.bbb.txt /tmp/patch.mr.txt
git diff /tmp/patch.bbb.txt /tmp/patch.mr.txt
kdiff3 /tmp/patch.bbb.txt /tmp/patch.mr.txt

You can also use git patch-id to compute the hash that git uses to say "these two commits are the same" (the one used by git rebase or git cherry or git log --cherry ...) :
git patch-id < /tmp/patch.bbb.txt
git patch-id < /tmp/patch.mr.txt

If the hashes match, this is a strong indication that the patches are "the same".

ok, you found out about comparing commits. added the mention to git patch-id. Also: even on Windows, you probably had git-bash installed together with git, and you should have access to several standard command like tools like diff or sed from a git-bash shell.
